# Notify Java server side (Tomcat) on DB (MySQL) changes

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc

Is there way to notify Java server side (Tomcat) on DB (MySQL) DML changes (specific table). I use JDBC.

All the time DB is changed from different services on server. I would like to notify Tomcat about it and change UI asap (e.g. web sockets, comet).
How to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean being notified about DML or DDL statements?

Comment: You may write a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) and run `wget` to inform tomcat http://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.com.es/2011/12/call-external-program-from-mysql.html

Comment: It might be better for your java app on tomcat to poll the DB every X seconds to see if it's changed.

Comment: Thanks for answers. DML changes. With regars to the trigger. It is interesting. But maybe more solutions. With regards to the poll DB every x seconds. it is the first thing that comes to mind. but I would like to present realtime applications. get from the database and  transmit through the socket to the user. I'll implement this solution if no better

Comment: who is that update the DB? I mean, if some application updates the DB, maybe it is more feasible to have the producer (who writes the DB) to signal the consumer (who read the DB) when new data is ready; the way to implement that depends on the writing application (I add that given the frenquency of "all the time DB is changed" you may have usability issue...)

Comment: Thanks for answers. I have oroginal post with more details but nobody answered because it is complex. Please red [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805743/real-time-web-tracking-app) for more details.

Comment: I've tried to answer to your original post... from an high level design point of view